mysqli::execute_query UPDATE many columns from webform
I am trying to UPDATE many columns in a mysql row using values passed from a webform.
I have to do this with several different tables and row combinations, so am trying to develop some reusable code, as coding in each QUERY with all the specified columns and parameters is a bit cumbersome and prone to alignment errors.
I think I am close to a solution that allows me to simply create a map of all the columns to be updated, making sure sure the associated $_REQUEST variables are named the same as the columns they correspond to.
However, I seem to be having issues with the formatting of the QUERY syntax having something to do with the parameter related to the WHERE section of the query.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong in the below code?
This is error I am getting "Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=?' at line .."
//list of the columns to be updated. These are also the variable names passed from webform via $_REQUEST global
$map1 = array(
'name',
'status',
'rel',
't1',
't2',
't3',
't4',
'gtsize',
'rate',
'preauth',
'qbadden',
'nsrv',
'regreq',
'freq',
'gtaccess',
'id_tech',
'bonus',
'drumvac',
'fortyaccess',
'dispas',
'email_man',
'parent',
'id_reg',
'notes_dispatch',
'notes_tech',
'notes'
);

$placeholder = "";
$params = [];
foreach($map1 as $key) {
   $placeholder .= ",$key=?";
   $params[] = $_REQUEST[$key];
}
// Cutting off the first ',' here
$placeholder = substr($placeholder, 1);

//add the additional and last value for the WHERE ID=? parameter to the parameter list
$params[] = $_REQUEST['SRVID'];


// for debugging:
//ECHO '<br>'.$placeholder.'<br>';
//var_dump($params);

$query = 'UPDATE services SET $placeholder WHERE id=?';
$result = $conn->execute_query($query, $params);


Well, what kind of error are you getting? Have you checked what the final generated query looks like? Give us a clue (because we can't run the code, mostly, and we can't see your input data that you're testing with either)

When I ECHO out $query, I get this : "UPDATE services SET $placeholder WHERE id=?"   So perhaps the use of a variable where $placeholder is does not resolve?

When I ECHO out $placeholder, I get : "name=?,status=?,rel=?,t1=?,t2=?,t3=?,t4=?,gtsize=?,rate=?,preauth=?,qbadden=?,nsrv=?,regreq=?,freq=?,gtaccess=?,id_tech=?,bonus=?,drumvac=?,fortyaccess=?,dispas=?,email_man=?,parent=?,id_reg=?,notes_dispatch=?,notes_tech=?,notes=?"
which seems correct.

The error I get is in the original post.

Turns out the issue was that the variable $placeholder was not getting resolved as a variable. I changed the line that assigns the $query variable to double quotes, and now it is working.
So from this :
$query = 'UPDATE services SET $placeholder WHERE id=?';

To this :
$query = "UPDATE services SET $placeholder WHERE id=?";

